# Angular's $interpolateProvider working only partially

Tags: angularjs

I have a really weird problem. I am using **$interpolateProvider** in my Angular app as I am passing some variables with Node which is **"{{ }}"** by default so I have set Angular's symbols to be: **"{[ ]}"**.

See below:

```
mainApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']}');
});
```

Now, this works everywhere except in one part of my app. See the HTML below:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="navBarController">

<li><a href="/profile#/profile">Profile</a></li>
<li>
<notification-icon count="{[notificationsCount]}"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i></notification-icon>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="/profileSettings#">Profile Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>
        <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
{[notificationsCount]}
</ul>
```

The bit that doesn't work is:

```
count="{[notificationsCount]}"
```

The bit that does work is right at the end:

```
{[notificationsCount]}
```

On the browser, I get [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7D&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B:%5D&p2=22&p3=%7B%5BnotificationsCount%5D%7D&p4=%7D) error from Angular and when I inspect the element, it is in plain text like: **{[notificationsCount]}** and doesn't get converted to the number which is does on the 2nd last line of the HTML code.

I suspect this might be due to the 3rd party module I am using, which is [angular-notification-icons](https://github.com/jacob-meacham/angular-notification-icons) but I can't be sure.

I have no idea how to proceed with this. Any input will help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need write without {[]} in place where the code doesn't work

```
<notification-icon count="notificationsCount"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i></notification-icon>
```

look carefully at the examples from https://github.com/jacob-meacham/angular-notification-icons , `notificationsCount`used directly such as directive attributes.

Comment: You the man! Worked. Gonna now proceed to hit my head against the wall for it's occasional lack of processing power. Thanks a lot!